# C++ Vectors / Classes /Threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, vector

I'm Using Win7 / VS2008 (9) SDK 6/7.1

i faced a problem in a code that i'm using
the mini version of the code as follows

```
class CONNECTION
{
    int/std::string/bool vars; // just to make it simple
    CONNECTION ( int defaultvar );
    CONNECTION ( const CONNECTION& copycon )
    ~CONNECTION ( );
    DWORD static WINAPI staticstart( void *param )  //HACK to use createthread on classes
    { return ((CONNECTION *)param)->main); } // yea it works fine
    DWORD main();
};
```

this class has no default constructor with a copy and a destructor
all vars are copied fine and destructor leaves no memleaks, constructor is simple as assigning the paramters to a var .. all vars and code are omitted to make it simple and because they aren't the prob.

```
class main
{
    std::vector<CONNECTION> con;
    int addcon( int defaultvarofcon )
    {
        CONNECTION temp( defaultvar );
        con.push_back( temp );
        return con.size() - 1;
    }
}
```

so far so good
when i run a console test program that only have an include and this code

```
main mymainclass;
mymainclass.addcon( 0 );
```

program runs fine closes without errors
but when i add extra code like

```
main mymainclass;
mymainclass.addcon( 0 );
mymainclass.addcon( 1 );
mymainclass.addcon( 2 );
```

program crashes with access violation
after checking my code twice i debugged it step by step on all threads i found out the main thread can read correct values of all vector class/elements in both main thread and worker thread ONLY if i'm using one element at the vector

however if i'm using more than one like the second code all data on all elements on their own threads are inaccessible ( bad pointers ) . but on main thread they still correct and showing right values

can any one please help me figure out what's wrong with this code ?

Comment: As any FYI because your class has a copy constructor and a destructor, it should almost certainy have an assignment operator.  It's unclear if this is related to your problem or not, but it's certainly a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: no it's not . maybe it might happen but it's not the problem now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is not designed to be thread safe.  Therefore you have to use some sort of mutex to make sure only one thread accesses it at a time.

Otherwise, if any thread resizes the vector, the vector may have to allocate new storage, copy elements, then free the old storage... and clearly freeing the old storage while some other thread is using it is a very bad thing.

You need to allocate the `CONNECTION` objects yourself.  Letting `std::vector` manage them means they are going to get moved around in memory when the vector resizes, and the pointers held by other threads are left dangling.  Resizing a vector invalidates all pointers to any of its content.

Comment: i have checked that . no variables are being cross-thread accessed . no variables are shared among threads either

Comment: i forgot, besides that i'm not talking about a shared variables . if you see the code upthere you'll see that i'm talking about the instance's variables . it's not shared nor accessed by any other threads.

Comment: @VirusEcks: Wait, are you creating new threads or not?  It looks like you're passing a pointer to a `CONNECTION` instance to `staticstart`, but the memory gets freed (when `std::vector` gets resized) and so when `staticstart` tries to call an instance method through that pointer, your program crashes.

Comment: @ben Voigt : the memory gets freed when vector is resized ? i didn't know that . BUT . in main thread i can see correct data . so memory isn't freed

Comment: @VIrusEcks: In main thread, you see correct data because the contents got copied to a new address before the old memory got freed.  But now it's a new address... all the pointers you're using in other threads still hold the old address, which no longer exists.

Comment: Solved by using std::List to get rid of the resizing ( reallocating ) problem .. thanks

Comment: @VirusEcks: That'll work, because in a `std::list`, existing iterators (pointers) aren't invalidated by inserting a new item.  You still can't use the list itself from two threads at once, but you can be sure the contents won't be moving around in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a custom destructor and copy constructor, you [probably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) also need a custom assignment operator.

Without that you quickly end up with several instances of your class referring to the same internal pointers/..., easily leading to memory corruption and access violations.